# Set the default owner of uploaded files by a user via FTP

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

When I upload files, the owner gets set to my username but the group gets set to "psacln"

I would like it to default to group "developers" of which i am part when I upload a file by FTP

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure this on server-side. You didn't specify what FTP server you are using.

For example with popular ProFTPD, you can use [`GroupOwner`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#GroupOwner) directive.

---

Theoretically, you can also setup your FTP client to "chgrp" every uploaded file. But there's no standard "chgrp" command in FTP. There's only non-standard `SITE CHGRP` feature. It's supported for example by ProFTPD server too. And I'm not aware of any FTP client that allows for automatic "chgrp" anyway.